# Symfony 3 redirect all routes except with specific prefix

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I'am trying to build an application using symfony and angular 2 and I was wondering if it is possible to redirect all routes to one specific action exept uri's that start with the /api prefix.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can take a look to 'kernel.controller' event [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-controller-event)

This event is triggered when the controller has been choosed but before executing it. So you can execute another one if route does'nt start with '/api' ...